# Blazor: ASPX URL Rewrite to Razor Page with Parameters processes then continues on to Not Found

Tags: asp.net, razor, routes, blazor, url-parameters

I use Url Rewriting to route my old .aspx pages to various pages in my Blazor Server App.  This is working quite well for the most part, however, I have a URL with Parameters that does go through the destination page, but ends up on the Not Found page.

I have tracked this down to the URL rewriter.  If I remove the .aspx from the URL the page processes properly, however, if I have the .aspx extension, it will find the Razor page, the code executes, but it continues on to some other page that then causes it to display the Not Found page.

Here is my Rewriter. the AmazonLAPConsent rule is the one relevant to this question.

```
RewriteOptions urlOptions = new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite(@"^(.*).ashx$", "api/$1", true);

urlOptions.AddRewrite(@"^(.*).inf$", "api/ComputerInfo", true);

urlOptions.AddRewrite(@"AmazonLAPconsent.aspx", "AmazonLAPconsent", true);

urlOptions.AddRewrite(@"^(.*).aspx$", "api/$1", true);

app.UseRewriter(urlOptions);
```

I have commented out the other .aspx extension rule with no change.  I have commented out all the rules except the one specific to this page with no change.

Why does the presence of the .aspx extension cause it to pass completely through the razor page and end up on the Not Found page?

As noted, I have commented out various code and so on, the only thing that makes a difference is the presence of the.aspx extension. I have also tried setting the rewriter boolean value to false, but the proper value is true which is supposed to prevent further rewriting.  Since I have removed the next .aspx rule by commenting it out it is not surprising that this does not fix it, as the next rule is not invoked anyway - or at least commenting it out has made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that all I needed was to add another @page directive:

```
@page "/AmazonLAPconsent"
@page "/AmazonLAPconsent.aspx"  <<<< this worked.
```